# Not getting Logs in logcat

Tags: android

In my application after a particular Activity the logcat stops working with the following Error message.
   **Segmentation fault      logcat -v long**

After that i have to start the Emulator again then only it shows the logs.

Can anyone pls help?

Answer (score 0):

go in devices view, click on dump hprof file (for devices view from eclipse menu : window->show view->other-android->devices)

Comment: Ok but when i click on hprof icon it shows unable to create HPROF file. please check the logcat for detail.

Comment: are u using usb cable to mount the sdcard? check the log,if it says file permissions issue..

Comment: logcat is not workind friend. and i am not using any cable, its about Emulator.

Comment: you said when you restart the emulator it works, isnt it? so restart the emulator, click on generate hprof file, see what is the error in logcat..

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

Go to the DDMS perspective of eclipse.

In the devices panel, there is View menu(shown with down arrow) next to minize button.
When you click on view menu there is button to reset adb. Click on that. It might fix the issues with the logcat.

Comment: Sorry friend but that is also not working. Logcat is stuck at the same line.